# Storing temp values in session array to use in mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, session

I have a view that needs updating with a list of id's. So I am storing the values that have been selected to remove from the view in a session variable that then goes into the mySQL query as below. Then when the form is reset the values are also reset out of the array.

But its not working... this is what I've got.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
if($_POST['flag']=='flag'){

    //collect deleted rows
    $_SESSION['delete-row'][] = $_POST['idval'];

    //Split session array

    $idavls = join(',' , $_session['delete-row'];



    $sqlDelete = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW filtetbl AS SELECT * FROM `".$page['db-name']."`.`leads_tbl` WHERE ".$_SESSION['filter-view']." AND `lead_status` = '1' AND `lead_id` NOT IN (".$idvals.") ORDER BY `lead_added`";


    $result = mysql_query($sqlDelete);

    if($result){

        echo true;
        }
        else{

            echo mysql_error();


        }

        }
```

Answer (score 0):

$_session isnt the same as $_SESSION for a start.

Also dont use mysql_query or similar (because it isnt safe) use [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: OK i'll look into that! Sorry typo on here but in my code its in capitals. Am I collecting the $_POST variables right?

Answer (score 0):

This is hard to correct without more information (and there are several errors - probaby cut and paste) so I'll pull apart one by one and you can go from there.

1 - $_SESSION['delete-row'][] = $_POST['idval'];

If 'idval' comes from multiple inputs (i.e.  ) then it is already an array, and you should have $_SESSION['delete-row'] = $_POST['idval']; If you are looping in an array of inputs (i.e. trying to append for many posts from  then it is correct)

2 - $idavls = join(',' , $_session['delete-row'];

$_SESSION (you said this was a type) and you also need a bracket/bract ar the end

1. - $sqlDelete = "CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW filtetbl AS SELECT * FROM `".$page['db-name']."`.`leads_tbl` WHERE ".$_SESSION['filter-view']." AND `lead_status` = '1' AND `lead_id` NOT IN (".$idvals.") ORDER BY `lead_added`";

Firsly this is very insecure as pointed out by allen213. Even if you don't use PDO to make safe the variable, please cast all the inputs as (int) assuming the IDs are integers, or at least wrap the input in mysql_real_escape_string().

Secondly, the logic in the question doesn't quite make sense. You say you want to remove IDs from the view, but what you are doing is recreating the view with only those IDs in $_SESSION['delete-row'] removed - so this may re-introduce IDs previously removed from the view. You'd actually need to keep $_SESSION['delete-row'] and keep adding to it to ensure the next time the view was created, then all the IDs are removed.

I hope that helps. If not, more code may be required (i.e. the form you are using the send data, anythign else that affects sessions etc.

Comment: I will keep adding to the $_SESSION['delete-row'] but only for one search. So the user creates an email list and then they can exclude an entry one by one. So sometimes the user will delete 10 and other times only one but the SESSION array will be different each time. I was more worried that I wasn't setting up the session array properly. I wanted to do something like $vals = $_SESSION['a'][]; but that doesn't work. Points noted about security, thank you!